# How to implement temporal constraint in tables by using trigger? I have to modify two rows at a time

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables namely, employees(id int, Name text, Dept text, Salary  numeric(10,2), Date tstzrange) and

employees_history having (id int, Salary numeric(10,2), valid_time_start tstzrange, valid_time_end tstzrange)

I want to create trigger in such a way,

a) When employees get job in my office I'll fill their id, Name, Dept and Salary and Date is obtained as a current Date(Date of employee joined job). and all related information should be inserted in employees_history. valid_time_end should contain "uc" i.e until change by trigger.

b) When employees get promotion then I'll increase their Salary and this must be reflected in employees_history table in such a way that employee id can occur multiple time in employees_history but valid_time_end should be date of promotion, and valid_time_end should be "uc". and if same employees is promoted then valid_time_end must be date of promotion by trigger.

Comment: Why are Date, valid_time_start, and valid_time_end all ranges?  It seems from your description that employees should have a timestamptz and employees history should have a start and end timestamptz or a single valid tstzrange.

Comment: it should have a start and end timestamptz.

Comment: or they could be dates, or it should have a single range.

Comment: they could be dates